# How to get input integer from user c

Tags: c, input, do-while

i want to get matrix values, rows and coloumn from user input. So i'm implementing `do while` to do this:
This is only for the rows:

```
do {
        printf ("Inserisci il numero di righe ( intero-positivo-diverso da 0): ");
        scanf ("%d",&righe);
    } while (righe<=0);
```

I want to check that user insert only integers. what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is correct. is the right way to do what you want...

Answer (score 2):

[`scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) returns an integer indicating how many "things" it successfully read. You can test this in a conditional to see if it got what you were looking for. Example:

```
const int result = scanf ("%d",&righe);
if (1 != result) {
  /* didn't get the 1 input we were looking for, do something about it! */
}
```

You'll want to distinguish between EOF and simply not an integer though.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value of `scanf()` it should return the number of converted strings, if it is != 1 the input couldn't be converted to an integer.

Reference :[scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this
[ctype.h](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha)